# Determining Cause of Unexpected Shutdown on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, compression, event-log

I left my computer unattended a little over half an hour while it was compressing some files. I came back, and my computer had apparently shut off. I looked at the Event Logs, and it told me that

```
The previous system shutdown at 2:51:38 PM on ‎6/‎2/‎2015 was unexpected.
```

The problem is that I was using the computer at that time, and it certainly did not shut down. It must have shut down sometime between 7:40 PM (when I left) and 8:20 PM (when I got back).

I'm using a laptop, and the only thing I can think of is that I had it set to battery saving mode (I forgot to turn battery saving mode off when I plugged it in), and that this may have interfered with the program I was using to compress the files (ALZip) once it went into sleep mode. Could that possibly have caused the shutdown?

Comment: usually battery saver will sleep or hibernate the laptop which is not an unexpected shutdown.

Comment: check all steps from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504/en-us

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an overheating problem, leading to thermal shutdown to self protect the computer. Does your computer fan run a lot during regular usage? Is there dust around the computer vents? Zip utilities do put stress on the CPU because they are resource intensive.

Comment: It think it's fairly doubtful that it's an overheating problem. The computer is virtually silent most of the time that I use it, and I clean the vents, fans, etc. periodically. I'm using a program called "Speed Fan", and the first core does have the "Fire" symbol that it puts on it, though it's only a few degrees over the "good" temperature when I'm doing compression (52 C on avg).